# Loading the ImageList to ListView doesn't work as intended in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

I try to load images from ImageList to ListView and it works great... but when the form is load, the last image of ImageList doesn't appear.... I will call this procedure at the combobox selectedIndexChanged event and at the form load... when the form load, the last image from ImageList doesn't appear and when I click the combobox for several times, all of the images appear as intended... Any help? 
Here is the code..

```
Private Sub LoadMenuItem()

    lvItem.Clear()
    Dim adptItem As New Restaurant_Management_SystemDataSetTableAdapters.ItemTableAdapter
    Dim categoryID As Integer = cboccategory.SelectedValue
    Dim dtItem As Restaurant_Management_SystemDataSet.ItemDataTable = adptItem.GetDataByCategoryID(categoryID)

    lvItem.BeginUpdate()
    For Each drItem As Restaurant_Management_SystemDataSet.ItemRow In dtItem.Rows
        Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(drItem.ImageForItem)
        Dim img As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
        ImageList1.Images.Add(drItem.ItemID, img)
        lvItem.Items.Add(drItem.ItemName.Trim, drItem.ItemID)
    Next
    lvItem.EndUpdate()

    cboItem.ValueMember = "ItemID"
    cboItem.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    cboItem.DataSource = dtItem
    lvItem.Refresh
End Sub
```